# How to determine number of frames using vision.VideoFileReader

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I've got a video, how could I determine number of frames in the video using matlab built-in function - `vision.VideoFileReader`?

It is not the same as VideoReader which I can get the number of frames by :

```
vidObj = VideoReader('varFrameRateFile.wmv');
numFrames = vidObj.NumberOfFrames;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
videoFReader = vision.VideoFileReader(FILENAME) 
Frames = 0;
while ~isDone(videoFReader)
  I = step(videoFReader);
  Frames = Frames+1;
end
```

Update : There is an alternative solution which does not require iteration over all frames in the video .

```
videoSource2=VideoReader(FILENAME);
frames=read(videoSource2);
totalFrameNumber=size(frames,4);
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: +1 - This is the **only** way to read the number of frames from the CVST video file reader.  However, if you don't want to do this, you can always use `VideoReader` and get the number of frames field as per the OP.

Comment: BTW, I fixed a minor typo in your code.  The `not` symbol in MATLAB is represented as `~`, and not `!`.